# How to correctly run graphical application in Docker container with Qt and D-Bus?

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, docker, qt, dbus

I was trying to get Audex [running](https://askubuntu.com/q/1244294/66509) inside 16.04 LTS Docker container on the 20.04 LTS host.

The below method works normally for Gtk-based applications, I have tested it.

In current case I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker.io
sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER
# reboot

mkdir ~/docker-audex
cat > ~/docker-audex/Dockerfile << EOF
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y audex
CMD audex
EOF

docker build -t ubuntu:audex ~/docker-audex
```

Then try to launch it from terminal and got the output:

> ```
> $ docker run -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" ubuntu:audex 
> QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application
> may misbehave. audex(7): KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus
> session server:  "/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the
> following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed. " 
>
> audex(6): KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.
> ```

or

> ````
> $ docker run -e DISPLAY -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" ubuntu:audex
>
> QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
> QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. audex(7):
> KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "Failed to
> connect to socket /run/user/1000/bus: No such file or directory" 
>
> audex(6): KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.```
> ````

or

> ```
> $ docker run -e DISPLAY -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /run:/run --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" ubuntu:audex
> QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. audex(7):
> KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "An
> AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this
> recipient; type="method_call", sender="(null)" (inactive)
> interface="org.freedesktop.DBus" member="Hello" error name="(unset)"
> requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.DBus" (bus)" 
>
> audex(6): KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.
> ```

and application window was not shown.

I suppose I have a problem  with D-Bus here. How can we fix it?

---

Update, following @SimonSudler [answer below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1249537/66509):

```
$ docker run -e DISPLAY -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS     -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /run:/run     --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)"     --security-opt apparmor=unconfined     ubuntu:audex

QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Error: Can not find password entry for uid 1000.
trying to create local folder //.kde: Permission denied
audex(7)/KSharedDataCache KSharedDataCache::Private::mapSharedMemory: Failed to establish shared memory mapping, will fallback to private memory -- memory usage will increase 
Usage: mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
  or:  mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
  or:  mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
      --backup[=CONTROL]       make a backup of each existing destination file
  -b                           like --backup but does not accept an argument
  -f, --force                  do not prompt before overwriting
  -i, --interactive            prompt before overwrite
  -n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file
If you specify more than one of -i, -f, -n, only the final one takes effect.
      --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE
                                 argument
  -S, --suffix=SUFFIX          override the usual backup suffix
  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
  -T, --no-target-directory    treat DEST as a normal file
  -u, --update                 move only when the SOURCE file is newer
                                 than the destination file or when the
                                 destination file is missing
  -v, --verbose                explain what is being done
  -Z, --context                set SELinux security context of destination
                                 file to default type
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.
The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through
the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:

  none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
  numbered, t     make numbered backups
  existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
  simple, never   always make simple backups

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Report mv translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mv>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) mv invocation'
audex(7)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
Error: Can not find password entry for uid 1000.
X Error: BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied) 10
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 1 (X_ShmAttach)
  Resource id:  0x12d
X Error: BadShmSeg (invalid shared segment parameter) 128
  Extension:    130 (MIT-SHM)
  Minor opcode: 5 (X_ShmCreatePixmap)
  Resource id:  0x3a00017
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00018
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00018
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00018
X Error: BadDrawable (invalid Pixmap or Window parameter) 9
  Major opcode: 62 (X_CopyArea)
  Resource id:  0x3a00018
```

adding [`--ipc=host`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1242399/66509) does not help either:

```
$ docker run --ipc=host -e DISPLAY -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS     -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /run:/run     --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)"     --security-opt apparmor=unconfined     ubuntu:audex
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
Error: Can not find password entry for uid 1000.
trying to create local folder //.kde: Permission denied
audex(7)/KSharedDataCache KSharedDataCache::Private::mapSharedMemory: Failed to establish shared memory mapping, will fallback to private memory -- memory usage will increase 
Usage: mv [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
  or:  mv [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
  or:  mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
Rename SOURCE to DEST, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
      --backup[=CONTROL]       make a backup of each existing destination file
  -b                           like --backup but does not accept an argument
  -f, --force                  do not prompt before overwriting
  -i, --interactive            prompt before overwrite
  -n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file
If you specify more than one of -i, -f, -n, only the final one takes effect.
      --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE
                                 argument
  -S, --suffix=SUFFIX          override the usual backup suffix
  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
  -T, --no-target-directory    treat DEST as a normal file
  -u, --update                 move only when the SOURCE file is newer
                                 than the destination file or when the
                                 destination file is missing
  -v, --verbose                explain what is being done
  -Z, --context                set SELinux security context of destination
                                 file to default type
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.
The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through
the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:

  none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)
  numbered, t     make numbered backups
  existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise
  simple, never   always make simple backups

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Report mv translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/mv>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) mv invocation'
audex(7)/kdecore (KConfigSkeleton) KCoreConfigSkeleton::writeConfig:
Error: Can not find password entry for uid 1000.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Run container without apparmor profile

The reason for this, is the [docker-default](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/apparmor/) profile for apparmor. The rules are integrated via [this template](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/profiles/apparmor/template.go) into the docker daemon.

There is a quick way to verify, if this profile causes the issue, add the `--security-opt apparmor=unconfined` to the `run` command:

```
docker run -e DISPLAY -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS \
    -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v /run:/run \
    --user="$(id --user):$(id --group)" \
    --security-opt apparmor=unconfined \
    -v /dev/sr0:/dev/sr0 \
    -v /dev/cdrom:/dev/cdrom \
    --privileged \
    ubuntu:audex
```

You could start to write an apparmor profile for audex, but I don't think it is worth the trouble. Since `audix` is a CD ripper, the user requires some "privileged" access to insert/remove CDs into the PC. So using the `apparmor=unconfined` should be secure enough.

#### Coredump of Audex

When `audex` starts, it executes several commands it expects to be encoders (e.g. `faac --help`). For some reason it also executes `mv --help`, which creates the weird output. At least that does not seem to be part of the problem. Also this behavior only occurs before the `~/.kde/share/config/audexrc` file is written. After that, only the crash remains...

Looking at the core dump of audex:

```
gdb /usr/bin/audex core.audex.3225
...
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f8799abda7f in KUrl::KUrl(QString const&) () from /usr/lib/libkdecore.so.5
#1  0x00007f879b4c7245 in KCompactDisc::cdromDeviceUrl(QString const&) () from /usr/lib/libkcompactdisc.so.4
#2  0x0000000000423469 in MainWindow::MainWindow (this=0x23ef580, parent=<optimized out>, __in_chrg=<optimized out>, 
    __vtt_parm=<optimized out>) at /build/buildd/audex-0.78/mainwindow.cpp:39
#3  0x000000000041a159 in main (argc=3, argv=0x7ffd939ccf58) at /build/buildd/audex-0.78/main.cpp:46
```

I seams that `audix` dies while trying to read the CD-ROM device URL. I added the `/dev/sr0` and `/dev/cdrom` to accommodate that, but it does not have any effect ([see handbreak example with docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934903/can-docker-write-to-a-cd)). Also adding the `audex` user in the container to the `cdrom` group did not help.

This seams to be a bug in old `audix` version from 16.04, which expects a legacy URL string.

It might be impossible to run `audex` from `ubuntu:16.04` on a current Ubuntu system because of some missing "old" KDE behavior. There is however a [Neon/Docker](https://community.kde.org/Neon/Docker) from KDE, but it requires also a KDE on the host.

Comment: Better, but still no window is shown. See update above. It complains about `mv` which is really strange.

Comment: @N0rbert do you have kde running on your host?

Comment: I'm running MATE on the host if this matters. Apps from KDE usually may be ran from other DEs, are not them? It is VM, so I'll try to install KDE to it and report back. Update: running from KDE does not help.

Comment: I updated the answer... I don't think it an work with the old binary. The rebuild approach from https://askubuntu.com/q/1244294/66509 might be the only way to get audex running.